# Copy text and picture into new word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

In the active word document I have a macro which extracts a text string and all images from the document.
I want to copy this text and the picture in a new blank word document.

I tried the following

```
Dim docNew As Document
Set docNew = Documents.Add

With ThisDocument    
                ...
                docNew.Content.Text = docNew.Content.Text & vbCrLf & sSentence
                For Each iShape In .InlineShapes
                    iShape.Select
                    Selection.CopyAsPicture
                    docNew.Content.Paste
                Next iShape
End With
```

When I execute this code, first the text is copied correctly to the new blank document. But when the picture is pasted, it overwrites the text and only the picture remains in the document.

How do I have to modify the code so that the text as well as all pictures are included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you would have discovered from looking at [the help text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.content) `.Content` represents the whole of the main body of the document.

Assuming you want to add the pictures at the end of the document, replace

```
docNew.Content.Paste
```

with

```
   With docNew.Content
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Paste
   End With
```